# get Eclipse to export libraries as a jar

Tags: eclipse, jar

How can I get Eclipse to export as a non-runnable jar all the contents of `JRE System Library [JavaSE-1.6]` and `Referenced Libraries`?

I want to use `-classpath` to bring together several jar files rather than use Eclipse's `Export > Runnable JAR file`.  Motivation: swapping out a single class that happens to be in a package of its own, by swapping the jar.

It's easy enough to export my own packages in (non-runnable) jars but now I need the "library" classes as well and I have not found an easy and obvious way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option when you export a runnable JAR to "Copy required libraries into a sub-folder next to the generated JAR". Would that work for your case?

Comment: I did that and those libraries seem to be sufficient even though they do not include the JRE libraries.  They appear in a folder not a single jar so a wildcard must be used.